# Puzzle #1: Love In the Air

Tags: calculation-puzzle

A couple that were just engaged decided to have their wedding in a hot air balloon. The biggest problem that the couple has is how many guests that they can invite.

There are three different types of hot air balloons that the aviation place allows for rent. The small hot air balloons cost 3 dollars and can hold 1 person, the medium cost 6 dollars and can hold 2 people, and the large cost 9 dollars and can hold 4 people.

There are 10 of each balloon type that are free on that day and the couple have a budget of $36. If the couple wants at least 2 of each type of balloon and will only get 2 large balloons, what is the maximum number of guests that they can invite?

Comment: Just so you know, I will just call these random puzzles that aren't worded like a riddle just "Puzzle- number". This is something that I want to get good at too, creating these kind of random puzzles too. I will stop trying to make the whodunit mysteries until I get good at these random puzzles, which is what I will be mostly making from now on. I think you have to be good at creating these puzzles before you attempt a whodunit mystery. Also, I will keep doing the riddles as well, but not as common. One more thing too, after today, August 26th, I will be absent until the night of August 31st.

Comment: Ohh... whodunnit puzzles will now also be absent :\

Comment: Well, until I get good at these more traditional puzzles

Comment: "One more thing too, after today, August 26th, I will be absent until the night of August 31st." -- I hope you will be able to prove it. Otherwise it won't be a valid alibi. `;)`

Comment: Well, you'll see that it's valid

Answer (score 1):

They can only invite

> 14

people.

Since if they have the get 2 of each size that automatically adds up to

> the max budget of 36

Since:

> Two large x 9 = 18

And

> Two medium x 6 = 12

And

> Two small x  3 = 6

(Excuse the horrendous formatting. Had trouble in phone app getting spoiler tags to work properly with other characters and was to the to look up how to escape characters.)

Answer (score 0):

> 16

They get

> 2 large + 2 medium + 2 small = 18 + 12 + 6 = $36

Comment: Yep, this was pretty easy. I will try to get better, I promise

Comment: Yeah. Decreasing the number of large boats available or increasing the budget would have helped increase the complexity a little

Answer (score 0):

> They can invite 12 people

Reason

> 2 large (4+4) , 2 medium, (2+2), 2 small(1+1) total 14 people minus the bride and groom we have 12 guest, the cost is 18+12+6=36$

Comment: I see what you're going for, but I'm not counting the bride and groom. They were prepaid for. Sorry, I've got a long way to go before I can write good puzzles. This one probably shouldn't even be considered a puzzle.